# how can I return to the previous page in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to know how to return to the previous page using a twig template no javascript, if it's possible.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In twig you can access:

```
app.request.headers.get('referer')
```

Hope this help

Comment: Trying this on Craft 3.2 and this tag above is just showing the current page URL. Has this changed with Craft 3?

Answer (score -1):

if you have need same route use

```
<a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route')) }}">Same page</a>
```